# Does .net core identity work with localdb?

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, identity, localdb

### I write an asp net core web spa React application

When I use `sqlite` db, provided by defatult `dotnet new react` template, everything runs okay.
But when I tried to migrate my db to reorganize several columns it said that `drop columns is not supported by "sqlite"`.
So I decided to use an `MSSQLLocalDb` instance.

### What I did

1. Erased `app.db` sqlite file.
2. Installed NuGet package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="3.1.4"`
3. Altered default connection string and context creation as shown below:

[image]

4. Ran `dotnet ef migrations add initial`
5. Ran `dotnet ef database update`
6. Ran `dotnet ef migrations add second` - just in case
7. Ran `dotnet ef database update`

DB created successfully. And now I'm facing a problem. I can't add any Identity role to the DB.
And so I can't add any role to any user.
Here the exception I get in my add-role method:

[image]

> What do I do wrong? Maybe there is a correct way to use another db type, not `sqlite` provided by default react template that doesn't break Identity mechanism?

My DbContext:

[image]

Comment: can we see your `DbContext` class?

Comment: Are you missing AddEntityFrameworkStores? e.g. services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#general-description-of-the-aspnet-core-components-of-the-app

Comment: @Rosco, no, they follow the code of ConfigureServices I provided. Just not at the screenshot.